# Reading an Excel spreadsheet in Delphi

Tags: delphi, import-from-excel

I have a number of applications that read Excel spreadsheets for conversion to SQL

All the applications are based on the same technique using the following procedures. Up to a recent install on one customers site it works perfectly.

**The procedures**

```
procedure TFormSpreadsheet.ConnectToExcel;
var strConn :  widestring;
begin
  strConn:='Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;' +
           'Data Source=' + edtSpreadsheet.Text + ';' +
           'Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;';
  showmessage(strConn);
  ConnectionIn.Connected:=False;
  ConnectionIn.ConnectionString:=strConn;
  try
    ConnectionIn.Open;
  except
    ShowMessage('Unable to connect to Excel, make sure the workbook ' + edtSpreadsheet.Text + ' exists!');
    raise;
  end;
end;(*ConnectToExcel*)

procedure TFormSpreadsheet.FetchData;

begin
  StatusBar1.SimpleText:='';

  ConnectToExcel;

  QrySpreadsheetIn.Close;

  QrySpreadsheetIn.SQL.Text:=MemoQry.Text;
  showmessage('qry is ' + memoqry.Text);
  try
    QrySpreadsheetIn.Open;
    clientdataset1.Open;
  except
    ShowMessage('Unable to read data from Excel, make sure the query ' + edtSpreadsheet.Text +
                 ' is meaningful!');
    raise;
  end;
end;
```

On this one site I get the message 'Unable to read data from Excel, make sure the query is meaningful'

The query reads 'Select * from [sheetname$]

which works on all other sites)

Showmessages run on the customers site show the connection succeeding but the opening of the query (which works on every other installation I have tried) fails.

Some additional info -

the process was developed in Delphi 7 on a 32bit system.
The failing installs are on a 64bit system, but I have successfully installed on other 64 bit systems.

I have read that there are some DLL's that may be missing or inactive but have been assured by the sites IT company that they should all be in order.

Has anyone got any ideas? Perhaps some code that could be used to prove what is wrong.

hanks in advance for any help/advise

Comment: Unfortunately your exception handler threw away all the useful information. You need to get the information out of the exception.